# Android How to increase program memory available. Like LargeHeap same effect

Tags: android

my application target is 2.2,not use largeHead:true;but,I need to use the same applications as largeHeap can use a lot of memory approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done in Android versions lower than Honeycomb. Sorry.